# Getting typing errors after upgrading expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx, tsx

I upgraded my project from expo 44 to expo 45 and now I have inumerous errors like this:

> The module 'MaterialIcons' can't be used as JSX component.

This error is happening with many libraries like react-native-paper, react-native-elements and even the native ones like expo-vector-icons.

If I rollback the upgrade everything gets back to normal, but I need to update to avoid having to do this later.

obs: I'm using typescript

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @ataravati Try adding the line I said below, delete node_modules and install using yarn again.

Or, try uninstalling node_modules and yarn.lock and install using npm ou expo upgrade --npm

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just had to use a different version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
}
```

to my package.json file.

It looks like yarn was using two different @types/react for the libraries, and this solved the issue.